# Why is my libgdx game not allowing me to run on android due to a duplicate file error?

Tags: android, libgdx, duplicates

I have been working on a simple game through libgdx and the desktop application has been working well but I simply cannot run the android version. I understand that I am supposed to link the desktop and android assets folders together (which I did), but my project will not run if there is no assets folder in my core (I heard that I am not supposed to need an assets folder there).

If the assets folder is present in my core folder, then I will get a "duplicate file" error, preventing me from running the apk but allowing me to run it as a desktop program. But if I remove the assets folder from the core, I will get an error saying that certain files cannot be loaded on both platforms (probably since I deleted the core assets folder).

Does anyone know what I can do to fix it and run the android program?

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question, my English is so bad, but you have to put all their assets in the android project and its code, inside the core, libgdx, link to other proyecctos for you.

just try using something like eg:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("youTextureInsedeProyectAndroid.png");
```

maybe you can look this

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game